# Serializing a String - possible?

Tags: java, serialization

Now this is a question for which I searched a lot of places,did a lot of coding but still am very confused. I am new to Java,so I was writing this program which saves an object data as a serialized object. The data members are two Strings. I read that when an object is serialized and stored in a file,the whole object state is saved. True. Then also the data is in binary form which cannot be read by humans or normal text editors. So when i stored the object using writeObject,it saved the data successfully,but when i open the file, it contains a lot of gibberish data,with the strings dispersed within. If i see a little more carefully, i can make out the strings clearly. So are the strings nit transformed into something else like in case of numerals??

Comment: are you opening the file using readObject? or in a text editor?

Comment: Why does it matter that you can see the strings in the serialized data file?

Comment: You question is different from the heading.. Going by your question heading..the answer is Yes it is possible to serialize a string.And if you are really concerned about safety of your string being serialized and saved in a file then better opt for the Encryption ..

Comment: Your question title is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

> So are the strings nit transformed into something else like in case of numerals?

The strings are serialized in length-prefixed modified UTF-8, I believe.

While generally serialized data isn't easily readable by humans, this shouldn't be treated as any sort of protection against people who want to read it. The serialization format is well-documented, and anyone who knows that it's the result of Java binary serialization is likely to be able to get significant data out of it.

If you need to keep data secure, you need another scheme *as well* as serialization. (I would also encourage you to investigate other serialization options. I'm not a big fan of Java serialization - it's very brittle. Making your data backward and forward compatible in the face of code changes is a little challenging.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no constraint that the result of serialization needs to be unreadable. When you serialize a string the string needs to be placed in the data, might as well just put it right in there, along with its length.

Serialization is not the most compact form possible, so you shouldn't be surprised that a string wasn't compressed somehow before being added to the byte stream.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I get what you and others are saying. If I write a serialized object containing strings,then relying on serialization alone that it will make the string data specifically unreadable would be foolishness.